# Django: 2 QuerySets and Duplicates

Tags: django

I have two QuerySets both containing the instances of the same model class.

```
class DBV:
    name = CharField
    description = TextField
    review_state = CharField(choices=[u"Draft",u"Published",u"Archived"])
    team_members = FK(User)
    deleted = Boolean
```

This is how I am filtering to get the two QuerySets:

```
res = DBV.objects.filter(deleted=False).filter(team_members=user)
if user.has_perm('dbv.can_view_dbv'):
    r = DBV.objects.filter(deleted=False).filter(review_state__in=[u'Published',u'Archived',])
    res = res + r
```

The first problem, of course, is that when you try to add QuerySets you get:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet'
```

So, what is the best way to merge these QuerySets and remove duplicates? I figure that there is isn't really a way to do that in Django besides writing the sql. Or?

Thank you! :)
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the queries to lists and add the lists, if you need both sets of results, or you can use "Q" objects and or them together to combine query logic: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: Ha! That is it. Thanks for the Q objects. Looks like that will solve my problem. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `|` operator. ie

`Queryset1 | Queryset2` this make the equivalent of union in sets. `Queryset1 & Queryset2` will give you the intersection of the sets